# Google Cloud service account auth without full json file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to programmatically (python) authenticate with Google Cloud when I'm only passed the `client_email` and `private_key` from the service account json file. Every library and code example I've found expects that you have the full json file. I know it's possible because I've used an application that supports it, I just don't know how it might be done in python.

Comment: I wrote an article on how to create OAuth tokens from a service account JSON file. Includes real working code. You could take my code and then experiment by removing various items until Google refuses to issue an Access Token. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Some Google services will accept a Signed-JWT (JWS), which is the first part of my code. Most Google services require that you exchange the JWS for an Access Token. The final answer depends on what services you plan to use.

Comment: @JohnHanley That's a clever solution. I'll be using storage services. But I'm not being passed the private_key_id.

Comment: I have seen examples that do not include the private key id. Experiment and let me know.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry, I misread your first comment where you suggested removing parts I didn't have. Your solution works though! If you want to post it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Where is your code running? Google has started to deploy the `--service-account` option which means you do not the JSON at all, just the email address. I wrote an article this week on how to use this feature for Cloud Run + KMS + Cloud Storage. No JSON keys. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-identity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an article on how to create OAuth tokens from a service account JSON file. Includes real working code. You could take my code and then experiment by removing various items until Google refuses to issue an Access Token.

[Google Cloud – Creating OAuth Access Tokens for REST API Calls](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/)